# phpvms and mySQL password rest

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, change-password

I brought a virtual airline and for my security I would like to change the password on the myphpadmin and mySQL.

I am very new to this and I'm not sure where to find this and or do it.

any help is very welcome

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your phpMyAdmin is protected by the MySQL authentication; so when you change your MySQL password it will also change for when you log in to phpMyAdmin. To do so, if you have the proper permissions, you'll see a link to "Change password" near the top of the "General settings" area of the main page. Note that in doing so, you will need to update the password in any other software that uses the same credentials, including phpMyAdmin only if you use the auth_type 'config'.

[image: Change password link]

If you don't see the link, your user account doesn't have permission to change the password directly. Some web hosting providers do this (I'm not sure why) and in many of those cases, provide some external means to change your password (perhaps through their management interface). However, in those cases it depends specifically on your provider and you'd have to ask their support staff for further assistance.